# Gulp: insert content from file into script

Tags: gulp

I've a JavaScript file `script.js` like this:

```
var myArray = {"INSERT":"ARRAY"};
```

Further I've a `array.json` file like this:

```
{
    "Item1": "Text1",
    "Item2": "Text2"
}
```

I would like `gulp` to replace the array in the `script.js` with the content in the `array.json` file. How can I do that?

I've been looking at `gulp-replace` and have this example:

```
gulp.task('my-task', [], function () {
    return gulp.src(['script.js'])
     .pipe(replace('{"INSERT":"ARRAY"}', '{"MY":"OTHER_ARRAY"}'))
     .pipe(gulp.dest("dist.js"));
});
```

where I successfully replace the text, but instead of replacing with a static array, I need to read the `array.json` file instead and use this instead. I'm not sure how I can do that or if there are any better solutions to this? I've been looking at `gulp-inject`, but I'm not sure if this can be used in my case?

Answer (score 5):

Just read the file contents?

```
gulp.task('my-task', [], function () {
    var replacement = fs.readFileSync('path/to/file');
    return gulp.src(['script.js'])
     .pipe(replace('{"INSERT":"ARRAY"}', replacement))
     .pipe(gulp.dest("dist.js"));
});
```